# Image getting completely white on downsampling

Tags: image-processing, matlab, downsampling

I performed an image downsampling with averaging operation(The image is divided into 2 by 2 blocks,then it is downsampled by 4 times.New pixel values od downsampled image is replaced with the mean of each block) as follows.

```
img = imread('cameraman.gif');
avgfilter = fspecial('average', [2 2]);
avgimg = filter2(avgfilter, img);
down1 = avgimg(1:2:end,1:2:end);
imshow(down1);
```

I used a graysacle image as input.

[image]

but I'm getting a complete white image as output on downsampling.
I tried with jpg image also. Why this happened?
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open an image using `imread`, you get the image as a `uint8` matrix with grayscale (or color) values of 0-255. However, filtering is no possible for this type. Therefore, `filter2` converts your image to `double`.
The function `imshow` accepts both `uint8` and `double` type. When the input is `uint8` it also assumes color values of 0-255. But, when the input is `double`, it assumes the values are normalised to the range of 0-1. Therefore you should tell `imshow` that although your input is of type `double` it has color values of 0-255 by using

```
imshow(down1,[0 255]);
```